# TestNGCucumberRunner with cucumber v6 not generating output files using parallel DataProvider

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, testng

Edit3: Was able to generate the TestNG outputs by executing through the Surefire plugin, but executing the suite from the IntelliJ TestNG runner still did not generate the output files.

Edit2: Removed jUnit from the project. Still not generating outputs.

Edit: Reduced the unnecesary dependencies / runner commands.

To summarize a bit, the problem that I'm currently facing is that I have setup Cucumber v6 along with TestNG v7, and DataProvider parallel runner.

I am executing the TestNG test suite (xml), which contains the @Test under the Runner class that gathers the scenarios through the @DataProvider (I believe this is a common setup).

Nevertheless, there are no TestNG output files generated at the end of the Suite.

This is my current setup for the project:

Runner:

```
package runners;

import java.util.*;

import io.cucumber.testng.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"./src/test/resources/features/"}
        , glue = {"stepDefinitions"}
        , plugin = {"pretty:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty.txt",
        "html:target/cucumber-reports/raw-cucumber-html-report.html",
        "json:target/report.json",
        , monochrome = true
)
public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    private static TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

    @Test(suiteName = "Suite", description = "Runs Cucumber Parallel Scenarios", dataProvider = "parallelScenarios")
    public void runParallelScenario(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) {
            testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
         
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] parallelScenarios() {
        if (testNGCucumberRunner == null) {
            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        }
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }
}
```

And the Suite.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test Suite" verbose="1" data-provider-thread-count="30">
    <test name="Scenario" verbose="1">
            <classes>
                <class name="runners.RunnerTest"/>
            </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.client.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.suite</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-suite</artifactId>
    <name>tests-suite</name>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- CUCUMBER DEPENDENCIES -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTNG DEPENDENCIES -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OTHER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <reportsDirectory>target/TestNG-Report</reportsDirectory>
                        <suiteXmlFile>Suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build</id>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>at.seresunit.lecturemanager_connector.App</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                    </transformer>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

So basically I'm executing the XML suite with IntelliJ, with the following params:

```
VM options: -ea -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag"
Working Directory: $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$
And pointing the path of the XML/modules
Also using Listeners > Use default reporters
```

Finally, the test are correctly executed, but there is no output folder with TestNG files.

Whenever I try to run:
`mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag"`

I get nothing executed and it shows the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ client-tests ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

I would like to have the Output files generated with minimal changes to the current setup.
Does somebody have any clue why they are not being generated, even calling the XML suite and using all TestNG annotations in the runner?

Thanks in advance.

Jackson.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but maybe not as important, that I only have 1 Scenario Outline with a lot of Examples.

Comment: At a glance I'm seeing different versions of Cucumber. You are also using both JUnit and TestNG. You have way to many things going on in your question. This means it is hard for people to help if, if they can do it at all. Start from scratch with a demo project and please read stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello. 
The cucumber versions I'm using are all 6.2.1, except the pico-container which does not have any more updated version. About jUnit, it's only called in the @RunWith annotation as far as I know, and nothing else about it is being used.

Comment: If that is true, then you should be able to remove a lot of stuff from your POM. You should do this work to make your problem minimal. It may even solve your problem. Btw you must be missing something about `cucumber-pico`. There are many newer versions: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for the correction. I have updated the cucumber pico-container version to 6.2.1. I have also trimmed the post removing a lot of peripherical features such as loggers/http services/etc. Now it should be pretty clean. Although, changing the version from pico-container did not solve the issue.

Comment: Its not about what you put into the post. It's about actually going through the process of making a small enough example that it can fit into your post. Doing this will help you eliminate all sorts of confounding factors. You have to do the work. You have to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you, I already edited the post and removed all unnecessary factors.

Comment: You are still mixing JUnit and TestNG in your POM.

Comment: Hello M.P Korstanje, I removed all jUnit related stuff from the project, and the output files are still not generated.

Comment: So... Keep going. There are many more things you can remove. Make the problem minimal. Do the work.

Answer (score 1):

The Surefire and Failssafe plugin would not skip your tests by itself. Either you skipped them explicitely in the command line or you skipped them in the parent POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.client.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Do NOT use surefire artifacts in your dependencies section. Please remove it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

And use the dependency within the plugin like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <reportsDirectory>target/TestNG-Report</reportsDirectory>
                    <suiteXmlFile>Suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                   <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                   <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. 

Adding the dependency inside the plugin element is giving the error: 

Invalid content was found starting with the element 'dependency'.

Also about the parent pom, there is nothing there, just the reference of the child poms and again, the dependency for the surefire plugin.

But the suite is inside the module which contains the child pom, so I don't see this being an issue.

Comment: I would also like to say that normally I'm running the suite through IntelliJ without the maven command, just by executing the xml suite directly.

Comment: Yes of cource. I fixed my comment and added <dependencies> within the plugin. I am wondering how you are using IntelliJ IDEA. You did not use auto-completion? IDEA will type anything for you if you e.g. type "<" then press CTRL+SPACE you should see that there must be the section "dependencies" and not "dependency". The same with Java code.

Comment: Right, now I could add it. Thanks for clarification. Nevertheless, the test with 'mvn test' command are still not executed.

Comment: What is inside of "target/surefire-reports"? There are really no reports and dump files? If they appear there, can you please upload all of them? Thx

Comment: If the directory "target/surefire-reports" would be empty, then please run the build with debug logs (mvn -X test) and upload them.

Comment: In the execution with -X param, I could see

```[DEBUG]   (s) skipTests = true```

But I have never set it to true...

Comment: oh right, that was located in the parent pom

Comment: Please put few +1 likes here, and we would be all happy. Thx